# how to get count new message found as per enquiry/ticket with two way conditions

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

i 'm working with crm application. i developed it finally i'm getting confused how i detect new messages as per flag must have display and message not have to true.

here is my db schema for understanding problem.

[image]
here is my constructed query to get new message count :

```
int new_messages = 0;
                foreach (var enquiry in db.Enquiries.Where(i => (i.ForwardTo.Equals(userid) || i.AttendBy.Equals(userid))).ToList())
                {
                    if (enquiry != null)
                    {
                        bool IsIns = true;
                        foreach (var flag in db.Flags.Where(f => f.Enquiry_History_id.Equals(enquiry.Ref_no) && f.User_id.Equals(userid)).Select(f => new { IsDisplay = f.IsDisplay }).ToList())
                        {
                            if (flag != null)
                            {
                                if (flag.IsDisplay == false)
                                {
                                    IsIns = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (IsIns == true)
                        {
                            foreach (var message in db.Messages.Where(m => m.Enquiry_History_id.Equals(enquiry.Ref_no) && m.User_id.Equals(userid)).Select(m => new { IsRead = m.IsRead }).ToList())
                            {
                                if (message.IsRead == true)
                                {
                                    //do another stuff
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    new_messages++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                lbl_msg.Text = new_messages.ToString();
```

here i have to take each enquiry that have been AttendBy or ForwardBy to user and check it first it should be display is not false and after that check as per each message should not have IsRead to true. i'm trying with my best way but this not gives me out put as i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have an idea just insert two values one for true which generate message and second for false to froward. and at finding out only which have IsRead to false.

something  like this way :

```
using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            string userid = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Ref_no).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
            bool IsIns = true;
            foreach (var enquiry in db.Enquiries.Where(i => i.AttendBy.Equals(userid) || i.ForwardTo.Equals(userid)).ToList())
            {
                if (enquiry != null)
                {
                    foreach (var flag in db.Flags.Where(f => f.Enquiry_History_id.Equals(enquiry.Ref_no) && f.User_id.Equals(userid)).Select(f => new { IsDisplay = f.IsDisplay }).ToList())
                    {
                        if (flag.IsDisplay == false)
                        {
                            IsIns = false;
                        }
                        if (IsIns == true)
                        {
                            foreach (var message in db.Messages.Where(m => m.Enquiry_History_id.Equals(enquiry.Ref_no)).ToList())
                            {
                                if (message != null)
                                {
                                    bool IsIns1 = false;
                                    foreach (var messageflag in db.MessageFlags.Where(mf => mf.MessageId.Equals(message.Id) && mf.UserId.Equals(userid)).Select(mf => new
                                    {
                                        IsRead = mf.IsRead,
                                        User_id = mf.UserId,
                                        Message = message.body,
                                        CreatedDate = message.Created_date
                                    }).ToList())
                                    {
                                        if (messageflag.IsRead == false)
                                        {
                                            IsIns1 = true;
                                        }
                                        if (IsIns1 == true)
                                        {
                                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                                            dr["Ref_no"] = enquiry.Ref_no.ToString();
                                            dr["Name"] = db.Users.Where(u => u.Ref_no.Equals(messageflag.User_id)).Select(u => u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
                                            dr["UserId"] = db.Users.Where(u => u.Ref_no.Equals(messageflag.User_id)).Select(u => u.Ref_no).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
                                            dr["Message"] = messageflag.Message.ToString();
                                            dr["CreatedDate"] = messageflag.CreatedDate.ToString();
                                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            myDataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
            lbl_count_messages.Text = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
            if (myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                message_alert.Visible = false;
            }
            Repeater_Messages.DataSource = myDataSet;
            Repeater_Messages.DataBind();
        }
```